# Vim the editor keeps crashing on Sierra

Tags: terminal, macos, crash, vi

I love using Vim through Terminal.app. Everything was fine until three days ago, when Vim starts to crashing. Each crash happens when I enter a newline(`'\n'`) character in the Edit Mode, but not every newline character entered would trigger a crash. Normally this happens once or twice a day.

For the full error report, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sunqingyao/dab7dc893a6f3718331ad8e6208d0171).

```
Process:               Terminal [23533]
Path:                  /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
Identifier:            com.apple.Terminal
Version:               2.7.1 (388)
Build Info:            Terminal-388000000000000~2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Terminal [23533]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-01-19 21:54:30.872 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.2 (16C67)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        FEDD969A-EA4B-329C-0B62-F0C04462CC4D

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C240156F-812D-4924-99DD-AF87AC1F5A65

Time Awake Since Boot: 160000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       10000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010c37b000-000000010c44b000 [  832K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fffe5d2cf56 _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell + 182
1   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c3b3c4d 0x10c37b000 + 232525
2   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c411bb8 0x10c37b000 + 617400
3   com.apple.UIFoundation          0x00007fffe3136b7f -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringUIFoundationAdditions) doubleClickAtIndex:inRange:] + 337
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffce6c090e -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringDeprecatedKitAdditions) URLAtIndex:effectiveRange:] + 607
5   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c41f625 0x10c37b000 + 673317
6   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c3eaf81 0x10c37b000 + 458625
7   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c3eb1e9 0x10c37b000 + 459241
8   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c3f1c1c 0x10c37b000 + 486428
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd2058f7f __NSFireTimer + 83
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd05cd244 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd05ccecf __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1071
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd05cca2a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd05c43e1 __CFRunLoopRun + 2065
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd05c3974 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffcfb4facc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffcfb4f901 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffcfb4f736 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffce0f5ae4 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffce87021f -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2789
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffce0ea465 -[NSApplication run] + 926
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffce0b4d80 NSApplicationMain + 1237
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffe5b1c255 start + 1

Thread 1:: com.apple.terminal.low-disk-space-handler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe5c4be2a kevent + 10
1   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c37d3df 0x10c37b000 + 9183
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd1fe8c6d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d33aab _pthread_body + 180
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d339f7 _pthread_start + 286
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d331fd thread_start + 13

Thread 2:: com.apple.terminal.sigchld-handler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe5c4c2da read + 10
1   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c387e03 0x10c37b000 + 52739
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd1fe8c6d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d33aab _pthread_body + 180
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d339f7 _pthread_start + 286
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d331fd thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.terminal.tty-io
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe5c4af4a __select + 10
1   com.apple.Terminal              0x000000010c38961b 0x10c37b000 + 58907
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd1fe8c6d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d33aab _pthread_body + 180
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d339f7 _pthread_start + 286
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d331fd thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe5c4338a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe5c427d7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd05c4c94 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd05c4121 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd05c3974 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffce242f92 _NSEventThread + 205
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d33aab _pthread_body + 180
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d339f7 _pthread_start + 286
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d331fd thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d331e0 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x6e69740000000000 0 + 7956017760075513856

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe5c4b4e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d33791 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d331ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d331e0 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x000000010c496000 0 + 4501102592

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffe5c4b4e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d335fe _pthread_wqthread + 1023
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe5d331ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff53881f0e  rbx: 0x000060000067d440  rcx: 0x000000000000ebb5  rdx: 0x0000000000000002
  rdi: 0x00007fff53881f0e  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007fff53881e70  rsp: 0x00007fff53881e70
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x00007fff53881e5c  r10: 0x00007f82dd284c30  r11: 0x00007fff53881f0e
  r12: 0x0000000000000018  r13: 0x0000000000000010  r14: 0x000000000000e22b  r15: 0x000000000003edb0
  rip: 0x00007fffe5d2cf56  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x10c37b000 -        0x10c44aff7  com.apple.Terminal (2.7.1 - 388) <3C674CD2-E649-3684-883C-A3A0B01DF572> /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
       0x110305000 -        0x110325fff  com.apple.CoreNLP (1.0 - 78.2) <D7A0704A-C4EB-3225-9F23-A06EC3318238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreNLP.framework/Versions/A/CoreNLP
       0x11039d000 -        0x1103a1fff  com.apple.audio.AppleHDAHALPlugIn (278.56 - 278.56) <BB9CA0DC-D58F-39C4-91C9-79B74666DF31> 
       ......


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 29
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 78111
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=263.0M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=263.0M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=167.3M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=167.3M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               256K        3 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
CG backing stores                 1172K        4 
CG image                           244K       16 
CoreAnimation                       16K        4 
CoreUI image data                  784K        9 
CoreUI image file                  288K        6 
Foundation                          20K        3 
Image IO                           204K        9 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                           136.0M       53 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       10 
Memory Tag 242                      12K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M       10 
Stack                             12.1M       10 
VM_ALLOCATE                        104K       16 
__DATA                            23.8M      231 
__GLSLBUILTINS                    2588K        2 
__IMAGE                            528K        2 
__LINKEDIT                       113.5M        9 
__TEXT                           149.6M      234 
__UNICODE                          556K        2 
mapped file                      160.0M       27 
shared memory                     16.4M       14 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            674.2M      656 

Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM MBA71.0166.B12, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.6 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000, Intel HD Graphics 6000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.68.1a4)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.2f4, 3 services, 17 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Ultra
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

Comment: For testing purposes could you install iTerm and run vim through that and see if you get the same behaviour?

Comment: I started experiencing this same issue (seemingly random editing of various files w/ vim, the terminal unexpectedly quits) starting about a week ago. [My report profile](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/23112926c5ac37d98baf09a18927488c) looks similar. Restarts and trashing of the terminal's pref file (`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`) didn't help. I haven't been able to identify any pattern to these segfaults and since I'm mostly in vim when in the Terminal, I wasn't even sure this is vim specific. Though so far I've only seen Terminal quit when I was actively editing in vim.

Comment: Not really a answer, but the homebrew version of vim might be more stable, having received more bug fixes.

Comment: @Deesbek I've already installed iterm2, but I need some time to monitor its crashing behavior, which occurs from time to time.

Comment: I faced similar issue, but that was fixed after the last update of the Terminal. I thought it was just me. Did you update Terminal within the last few days?

Comment: @fayazmiraz How to update Terminal? I received no update notifications for the last week, and App Store tells me "No Updates Available".

Comment: Basically I didn't exactly get the update for the Terminal App, I got the Update for "Command Line Tools" which I use with Xcode. I have no idea how that update along with macOS 10.12.2 update fixed my Vim issue. I also use homebrew. But like I said, I only know it's fixed for me, don't know how (didn't have the time to investigate).

Comment: @Fayaz you should post that comment as an answer if that fixed the issue. I use iTerm2 so could not replicate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is failing reliably for me too. For me it only happens with vim running on a remote machine using ssh. Vim does seem to be the common factor.

According to this [Google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_mac/u1KcVADERtc), the problem can be reproduced by putting this into a file:

```
/goldbaum2-7.bmv already exists; use -y to recreate 
/des_surveyBuildup_11-7.bmv already exists; use -y to recreate 
/lsst_telescope12-22.bmv 1-2660 /fe0/deslsst/telescope/comps/lsst_obj_12-22_comp4k/lsst_obj_12-22_comp4k.%04d.png 
img2bmv -f 30 -p 3 -N 6 -L 42  -t 512x360 -w 4096x2160  -w 3840x2160 -t 480x540  -o /fraid0/movies/ren400My_vars_grids_labels_11-8.bmv 1-2881 /fe0/deslsst/renaissance/comps/ren400My_vars_grids_labels_3840_11-8/ren400My_vars_grids_labels_3840_11-8.%04d.png 
Don't know how to make these movies:  -f 3
```

Then editing it with vim and executing the command sequence `3jdfo`. This reproduces the problem for me.

This is clearly a bug in Terminal.app's handling of an escape sequence generated by vim. Hopefully there will be a fix in the next OSX update.

Update: I have also seen the problem with command-line history editing with `zsh` in vi mode. Clearly a problem in Terminal.app.

Update 2: The test case no longer crashes Terminal.app after the 10.12.4 update. Solution: Update to 10.12.4.

Answer (score 2):

Using Sierra 10.12.3 and macvim installed via macports, I do not get crashes, per se, when running macvim through the Terminal.app, but it **is** incredibly "laggy".  In particular, switching focus back and forth between the macvim window and any Terminal.app window can take up to a minute.

Someone in another thread [on nabble](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/MacOS-Sierra-10-12-1-Terminal-app-crashes-while-using-Vim-td5728710.html) claimed that the crashes with vim can be avoided by declaring Terminal.app to be anything other than xterm, xterm-16, or xterm-256.  That might fix the crash problem but it does not help with the sluggishness I am experiencing.